# How to return a value in WndProc for C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, wndproc

In my application, I hid the cursor using `SetCursor(NULL)` and to make sure that Windows does not reset the cursor state, I handled `WM_SETCURSOR` in my `WndProc` method.

However in the msdn documentation for C++, in order to handle `WM_SETCURSOR` I have to `return TRUE`. However in C#'s WndProc, it is a void method so I cannot return any value.

So how would I accomplish that return statement in C#?

C++ Variant:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,
{        
    case WM_SETCURSOR:
        if (LOWORD(lParam) == HTCLIENT)
        {
            SetCursor(hCursor);
            return TRUE;
        }
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return without calling `base.WndProc`:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
    if(m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR) {
        int lowWord = (m.LParam.ToInt32() << 16) >> 16;
        if(lowWord == HTCLIENT){
          SetCursor(hCursor);
          return;
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

I guess this also works (I've experienced it with some messages but not sure with `WM_SETCURSOR`):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){     
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if(m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR) {
        int lowWord = (m.LParam.ToInt32() << 16) >> 16;
        if(lowWord == HTCLIENT){
          SetCursor(hCursor);
          m.Result = new IntPtr(1);
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: In the second example, is there a reason you put `base.WndProc(ref m)` first?

Comment: @azian.otaku yes, you have to do `base.WndProc(ref m)` first so that the return value will be put in `m.Result`. Otherwise `m.Result` is always `IntPtr.Zero` (I guess so).

Comment: In these two examples, do you recommend one way over another?

Comment: @azian.otaku I usually go for the first because of simple logic. However in some cases you need to deal with the return result `m.Result` so we need the second.

Comment: For anybody else confused by this at first - the first thing to understand is that you don't change the void return type, you put the return value in m.Result. *Then* you have to deal with the fact that base.WndProc(ref m) will actually override your result if you call it last, so call it first.